Is there a way to get set_environment_texture to work with streamlit stpyvista
I have this code and it works when I run it with pyvista but with stpyvista the cubemap does not show up and it has a white background
This is what it looks like when I run it with stpyvista and   This is what it looks like with pyvista
light = pv.Light()
light.set_direction_angle(30, -20) 

mars = examples.planets.load_mars(radius=3397.2)
mars_texture = examples.planets.download_mars_surface(texture=True)
mars.translate((-30000.0, 0.0, 0.0), inplace=True)

plotter = pv.Plotter(lighting="none")

cubemap = examples.download_cubemap_space_16k()
_ = plotter.add_actor(cubemap.to_skybox())
plotter.set_environment_texture(cubemap, True) 
plotter.add_light(light)
plotter.add_mesh(mars, texture=mars_texture, smooth_shading=True)
plotter.view_isometric()

stpyvista(plotter)


